# Split a group in two based on lowest possible travel distance

Tags: python, pandas, math, mathematical-optimization

I'm trying to split a group of 80 people in two. The groups will each have to travel to a location. I am trying to split the group so that people have to travel as little as possible. I'm interested in the least total travel time, but I also want it to be balanced so we don't have a few people travel very far, even if it means everyone else will have shorter distance.

My data looks something like this:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
|        Person       |    Distance 1    |    Distance 2    |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|       Person 1      |      0:56:52     |      1:23:50     |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|       Person 2      |      0:42:55     |      0:22:45     |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|       Person 3      |      1:32:35     |      2:23:02     |
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

I'd like to add another column with 'A' or 'B' depending on which group they should be placed in. The people need to be divided evenly among the two groups, so as to **minimize the square of the travel times**. I'm aware that some kind of mathematical optimization might be the way to go, I'm just not sure how to go about it. I'm using python (pandas).

Comment: Hi Bertil. You should define what you mean by 'balanced' in a mathematical way, otherwise the problem is not well defined.

Comment: Thanks, I'll work on that and edit my question asap.

Comment: A way to do it would be to minimize the square of the travel times, this way the long travel times get higher importance in the minimalisation than in the linear minimalisation.

Comment: Yes @zabop, that's perfect!

Comment: To be clear I’m still unsure about how to actually go about this

Comment: Not ready w an answer yet but the way I would go about it: start with a smaller dataset, split it into two parts, do it every possible way, then check squared sum of each split, then decide which split is the best.

Comment: Alright, makes sense. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can model the math problem like this.

http://mathb.in/31885?key=216f0d8271c8a65ecbce2faff12735042a4b7684

where x_i is 1 if traveler i is assigned to group 1 and 0 if assigned to group 2. the distance for traveler i for group 1 is d and for group 2 is d'

Then you can use integer solvers like gurobi/pulp to do the computation in python.

There are other formulations possible, depending on how you define "balanced". I am guessing the square of total travel time will give you the kind of split you want. You can solve this and see if you like the solution you get. But there are possibly other formulations you can have of balance. One example may be, "the maximum one traveler should travel is less than some 'D_high'. In that case you will add a constraint such as x_i d_i + (1-x_i)d'_i<= D_high

This is a relatively small problem for most modern solvers and you should get an answer in matter of minutes.

EDIT: Just realized that pulp/gurobi are linear solvers. If you use the square as an objective that is non-linear integer and you can no longer use gurobi/pulp. You have two options:

1. Stick with the non-linear formulation and use cvxpy (open source convex optimization, has support for integer variables as well, as far as I remember)
2. Go for a linear formulation where your objective is only the sum of distances rather than the square sum. And impose a linear constraint like I mentioned before  x_i d_i + (1-x_i)d'_i<= D_high, to impose restriction on some sort of fairness

Comment: Thanks so much, I'm working from this, trying to figure out how to do it in pulp. It's not so easy working with sums and all. I might return with questions if I can't figure it out.

Comment: I made some edits pertaining to your planned use of pulp

Comment: Ah, thanks a lot! That makes sense. I'm going to try with the linear version for now, as I've just been getting into pulp. Will update and try with cvxpy later if I have time.

Comment: If you liked the answer, please take some time to accept it